# do not want to check a check box which is disabled

Tags: jquery

i have check box list and some of them are disable. i have a check box of `check_all` and `uncheckall` and my code is

```
$( '#check_all' ).live( 'change', function() {
   $( '.waiting_user' ).attr( 'checked', $( this ).is( ':checked' ) ? 'checked' : '' );
   $( this ).next().text( $( this ).is( ':checked' ) ? 'Uncheck All' : 'Check All' );
 });
```

its working fine but problem is that it check and uncheck disabled checkbox also

any way to do that checkall and unchekall only enabled echeck box se in image to more detail[image]

and problem is its cheked disabled checkbox also.

[image]

Comment: `live` is deprecated. Please use event delegation using `on`. You can find more about the `on` method in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude the disabled checkboxes as such:

```
$('.waiting_user:not(:disabled)')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the psuedo class selector `:enabled`

```
 $( '.waiting_user:enabled' ).attr( 'checked', $( this ).is( ':checked' ) ? 'checked' : '' );
```

Comment: +1 that is of course a less roundabout way than what I was suggesting.

Comment: @David Hedlund I try to follow a practice I picked up in some programming books that says not to deal with negative logic, to always use positive logic.  Of course this is style and preference, sometimes it can't be avoided, both answers work.

Comment: Nah, this is way neater, I just wasn't familiar with the `:enabled` selector. I guess I've been used to thinking in terms of disabled because that's how the HTML attribute works. I have to go back and look over my own codebase now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( '#check_all' ).live( 'change', function() {
$( '.waiting_user:enabled").attr( 'checked', $( this ).is( ':checked' )  ? 'checked' : '' );
$( this ).next().text( $( this ).is( ':checked' ) ? 'Uncheck All' : 'Check All' );
});
```